# SynchronizationLockException in AKKA.NET mailboxes

Tags: .net, akka.net

I using AKKA.NET in my project. There was nessesary to use Mailboxes for set priority for messages for actor. According the article https://getakka.net/articles/actors/mailboxes.html I created mailbox:

```
public class MyActorMailBox: UnboundedPriorityMailbox
{
    public MyActorMailBox(Settings settings, Config config) : base(settings, config)
    {}

    protected override int PriorityGenerator(object message)
    {
        if (message is MyActorMailBox.ErroredMessage)
            return 0;
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Creation of actor instance:

```
   ActorSystem.ActorOf(
        Props.Create(() => new MyActor()).WithMailbox("myactor-mailbox"), "MyActor");
```

After that I added settings to App.config:

```
  <!-- language: lang-xml -->
  <akka>
    <hocon>
      <![CDATA[
      akka
      {...}
      myactor-mailbox
      {     
         mailbox-type="MyActorMailBox, MyNamespace"
      }
      ]]>
    </hocon>
  </akka>
```

I have System.Threading.SynchronizationLockException: Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code. I guess it connected with unsynchronized messages queue in mailbox by default. Callstack doesn't have details about type of message:

```
Swallowing exception during message send
System.Threading.SynchronizationLockException: Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code.
   at Akka.Dispatch.MessageQueues.BlockingMessageQueue.Enqueue(IActorRef receiver, Envelope envelope)
   at Akka.Dispatch.MessageDispatcher.Dispatch(ActorCell cell, Envelope envelope)
   at Akka.Actor.ActorCell.SendMessage(Envelope message)
```

Any ideas to resolve that problem?
Thanx

Comment: Looks like this might be a bug - going to investigate. I've opened and issue here: https://github.com/akkadotnet/akka.net/issues/3459

Comment: If you wouldn't mind commenting on that Github thread with the version of Akka.NET you're using, I'd appreciate it!

Comment: Thank you for investigating:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug in the design of our custom mailbox code in Akka.NET. It was fixed in patch v1.3.8. You can follow the bugfix thread here: https://github.com/akkadotnet/akka.net/issues/3459